# Azure Mobile Back End Can't add records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I have a Xamarin Mobile App using an Azure App Service Back End.  Everything seems to work except when I want to add records.  My class is as follows:

```
public partial class Site : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public Site()
    {
        SiteMarks = new ObservableCollection<SiteMark>();
        DelSiteMarks = new ObservableCollection<SiteMark>();
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
        if ((propertyChanged != null))
        {
            propertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "SiteID")]
    public string SiteID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Address")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Note")]
    public string Note { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Icon")]
    public string Icon { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Lat")]
    public double? Lat { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Lng")]
    public double? Lng { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    private string _MarkerID;
    public string MarkerID
    {
        get
        {
            return _MarkerID;
        }
        set
        {
            _MarkerID = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MarkerID");
        }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public ObservableCollection<SiteMark> SiteMarks { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public ObservableCollection<SiteMark> DelSiteMarks { get; set; }

}
```

I create a new site as so:

```
Site site = new Site();
site.SiteMarks = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<SiteMark>();
site.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
site.SiteID = SiteID;
site.Name = Name;
site.Address = Address;
site.Lat = Lat;
site.Lng = Lng;
```

Then I just call:

```
await SiteTable.UpdateAsync(site);
```

Should be simple but I keep getting

> The request could not be completed.  (Bad Request)

I wish there were more information so help figure out why the request is bad.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might track this down?

*** Update ***

I had put the call stack but it was obnoxiously long.  I have removed it.  I found the problem and will post an answer.

Comment: Try to use fiddler trace to get the detail of the error message.

Comment: Is authentication successfully passed?

Comment: @SwikrutiBose I added the stack trace from the error in Xamarin.  How do you use Fiddler?  Is it part of Visual Studio?

Comment: @ThuanNg I think the authentication is OK.  It will read and update records just fine.  It just won't add new ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually a little embarrassing. Due to some of the comments, I looked into debugging the actual service running on Azure.  When I got the debug trace from that, I found that it was not able to find MarkerID.  So the skinny of it is:

```
[JsonIgnore]
private string _MarkerID;
public string MarkerID
{
    get
    {
        return _MarkerID;
    }
    set
    {
        _MarkerID = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("MarkerID");
    }
}
```

Really needed to be

```
private string _MarkerID;
[JsonIgnore]
public string MarkerID
{
    get
    {
        return _MarkerID;
    }
    set
    {
        _MarkerID = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("MarkerID");
    }
}
```

I was ignoring the private variable rather than the public property.  Once I fixed this, it worked great!  Thanks to all who helped.